# org-babel syntax highlighting with one language, executing with another

Tags: org-babel

I'd like to set a `#+begin_src ... #+end_src` block so that it highlights syntax with one language, while `org-babel-execute` executes with another language.
Namely: I work with metapost code within a block that I want to be executed with `org-babel-execute:latex`.

I tried to declare the language in the block header as metapost and set metapost as an alias to latex in `org-src-lang-modes`, but then the syntax highlighting follows latex.

Comment: Write an `ob-metapost.el` that defines `org-babel-execute:metapost` the way you want? I don't think you can do what you want with any existing functionality, but writing a babel back end for `metapost` should be fairly easy. And once you've written it, announce it on the Org mode ML! Before you start, check if one exists already: I didn't find one but that does not mean much.

Comment: Actually, the block should be processed as a latex block, so `ob-latex` is ok to this purpose (except for the syntax highlighting). The metapost code is embedded in a latex environment. Unfortunately, I am not good enough at elisp to be able to write a brand new backend.

Comment: You can edit the code with `C-c '` in a separate buffer. In that buffer, you can switch the mode manually to `metapost-mode` (or whatever...). When you are done editing, another `C-c '` updates the Org mode buffer with your changes to the code block. Would that work?